# Python: Search for string from dictionaryCSV file and display matching rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, search

I have this program right now where it allows users to choose from a category(pulling from the file). Then it will print the University data using dictionary.

What I want to do next on my code is for users to search for a specific string from that file and it will display all of the keys. It can be the whole word or part of the string from that file.

I need help on searching for a given string or part of a string and display matching categories (NameID, StudentName, University, Phone, State).

**Example:**

**search**: on

**output:** (Note: that this is in dictionary format)

```
{'NameID': 'JSNOW', ' StudentName': ' Jon Snow', ' University': ' UofWinterfell', ' Phone': ' 324234423', ' State': 'Westeros'}
{'NameID': 'JJONS', ' StudentName': ' Joe Jonson', ' University': ' NYU', ' Phone': ' 123432333', ' State': 'New York'}
```

My text file looks like this:

```
NameID, StudentName, University, Phone, State
JJONS, Joe Jonson, NYU, 123432333, New York
SROGE, Steve Rogers,  UofI, 324324423, New York
JSNOW, Jon Snow, UofWinterfell, 324234423, Westeros
DTARG, Daenerys Targaryen, Dragonstone, 345345, NULL
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv

def load_data(file_name):
  university_data=[]
  with open("file.csv", mode='r') as csv_file:
      csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
      for col in csv_reader:
        university_data.append(dict(col))
        print(university_data)
  return university_data

# def search_file():
#   for l in data:
#         no idea what to do here

def main():
    filename='file.csv'
    university_data = load_data(filename)
    print('[1] University\n[2] Student Name\n[3] Exit\n[4] Search')
    while True:

        choice=input('Enter choice 1/2/3? ')
        if choice=='1':
            for university in university_data:
                print(university['University'])
        elif choice=='2':
            for university in university_data:
                print(university['StudentName'])
        elif choice =='3':
            print('Thank You')
            break
        elif choice =='4':
          search_file()

        else:
            print('Invalid selection')
main()
```

I need choice 4 to work. I would ignore the choice 1 and 2 because they just display the names and is not in dictionary format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out which field you are searching by and then iterate over the list of dicts.

```
def search_file(field, query):
    for l in data:
        if l.get(field, None) == query:
            return l
```

Comment: will that field be like 'University' in my case scenario?